# How do I access the command line argument variable when making an alias in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I'm making a few aliases to speed up my development processes.

Right now I'm trying to make a `cdls` which is quite obviously a `cd {arbitrary-file} && ls {arbitrary-file}`

I was under the impression that `alias cdls='cd $@ && ls $@` would work, but it looks like I was mistaken about `$@` carrying the argument (file path) since this sends me back to my $HOME directory every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases don't process arguments. Use a function instead:

```
cdls () {
    cd "$1"
    ls
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try instead in .bash_profile

`function cdls () {  ls "$@" && eval cd "\"\$$#\"";}`

I don't remember where I got that from but I have something similar to it working.

Comment: Lol it doesn't. Fixed. Started that answer thinking he was piping and never changed that first sentence.